# Add google spreadsheet notes in clipboard

Tags: google-sheets, clipboard

I am currently creating a html table in javascript and putting it in clipboard to be pasted into a google sheet. However, I also need some cells to have comments and I can't get them added.

I am using [this](http://www.peterbuettner.de/develop/tools/clipview/index.html) clipboard viewer to understand how the google sheets do it, but I can't get it working nevertheless.

I entered some data into a google spreadsheet and copied a row of empty cell, cell with a value and cell with a value and a note. Here is (a formatted version of) what I had in my clipboard (html version) when I copied from the google sheet:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <!--StartFragment-->
        <meta name="generator" content="Sheets"/>
        <style type="text/css">
            <!--
                td {border: 1px solid #ccc;}
                br {mso-data-placement:same-cell;}
            -->
        </style>

        <table 
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
            cellspacing="0" 
            cellpadding="0" 
            dir="ltr" 
            border="1" 
            style="
                table-layout:fixed;
                font-size:10pt;
                font-family:
                arial,sans,sans-serif;
                width:0px;
                border-collapse:collapse;
                border:none" >

            <colgroup>
                <col width="100"/>
                <col width="100"/>
                <col width="100"/>
            </colgroup>

            <tbody>
                <tr style="height:21px;">
                    <td 
                        style="
                            overflow:hidden;
                            padding:2px 3px 2px 3px;
                            vertical-align:bottom;" >
                    </td>
                    <td 
                        style="
                            overflow:hidden;
                            padding:2px 3px 2px 3px;
                            vertical-align:bottom;
                            text-align:right;" 
                        data-sheets-value="{&quot;1&quot;:3,&quot;3&quot;:0}" >
                            0
                    </td>
                    <td 
                        style="
                            overflow:hidden;
                            padding:2px 3px 2px 3px;
                            vertical-align:bottom;" 
                        data-sheets-value="{&quot;1&quot;:2,&quot;2&quot;:&quot;?&quot;}" 
                        data-sheets-note="test note">
                            ?
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <!--EndFragment-->
    </body>
</html>
```

If I paste in another place, the note is pasted as well, so this somehow works.

It seems that the key should be the `data-sheets-note` attribute, but it doesn't work like that. For example, I pushed the following into the clipboard (HTML format):

```
<html>
    <body>
        <!--StartFragment-->
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td data-sheets-note="test2">2</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <!--EndFragment-->
    </body>
</html>
```

And it pastes into spreadsheet but the note is not added to the cell.

If I take the previous example and push it in clipboard (HTML format) again, I can once again paste into a google sheet and the note is added as well, so the format is the correct one and the attribute to store note in is also the correct one (as it's the only place holding that note contents and it gets pasted).

What am I missing then?

Comment: I wrote the question so thoroughly that I managed to find an answer. Still decided to post it - it might help for others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `data-sheets-note` attribute is indeed the correct one. But, to get it accepted, we need to lie. It must be told that the clipboard contents was generated by google sheets themselves.

We can tell that using the meta tag:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <!--StartFragment-->
        <meta name="generator" content="Sheets"/>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td data-sheets-note="test2">2</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <!--EndFragment-->
    </body>
</html>
```

Now the sheet will recognize the comment as well.