# Generating clipboard data to past into google sheets

Tags: python, google-sheets, formatting, clipboard

Is there anyway to generate clipboard data that I can paste into google sheets to generate formatting? I.e. use python to save a generate and save info to the clipboard using pyperclip or something that contains more than just cell text information (like cell color, border etc.).

Alternatively, when I copy data in google sheets is there anyway to access to formatting information and edit that myself using something like a python script?

Thanks!

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50455314/add-google-spreadsheet-notes-in-clipboard https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/clipboard+google-sheets

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.